# Prevention from cross site scripting in different scenerio?

Tags: xss, encoding, validation

I could not validate malicious characters like ' .< > etc because these characters are required in my application. Also I could not encode characters because user supposed to enter HTML tags in my application so in case we encode characters, html tags not rendered on browser.

So i have made a filter which blocked  and  tags only. Is there any other approach or any other characters or strings which i need to blocked??

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the approach you're taking to preventing Cross-Site Scripting is black-listing specific tags.

This approach is very difficult to maintain and would not be a recommended one as there are always new tags and parameters which could allow for Cross-Site scripting coming along, so it requires constant maintenance.  A good example of the variety of vectors that can be used for XSS is [here](http://html5sec.org/).

If you need your users to be able to use rich content on the site (perhaps for formatting text), then perhaps another option would be to look at languages like [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) which could allow users to enter richer text, without the dangers of pure HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than blocking, you could allow any tags to be entered, but you could prevent script execution when output by implementing a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/).

This is executed by the output of a HTTP header on all pages of your site (or at the very  least all user content pages).

e.g.

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

will only allow script files on your own domain from being accessed. If the user included any of their own code in `<script>` tags, attributes (`onclick="doEvil();"`) or referenced code on other domains (`<script src="http://www.example.com/evil.js"></script>`) they would not be executed. If you are going down this route your should either limit `default-src` (which will affect everything from XHR requests, font sources, image sources, etc) to `self` (i.e. same origin) or at the very minimum you should limit `script-src` and `style-src` which will prevent external and inline scripts and css code.

The only downside I see of this approach is that older browsers may not support CSP. You may be able to detect this and then show a "safe" plain text version of the content to these users. For example, strip all tags and then **HTML encode**  on output (to prevent any tags that may have sneaked through). Supporting browsers are [listed here](http://caniuse.com/contentsecuritypolicy).